# Move-Item with Exclude doesn't work

Tags: powershell

I have two scripts which should do the same but the first doesn't work and the second does. Why is that? I have managed to figure out it has something to do with the Execlude. It says:

```
Move-Item : Cannot move item because the item at 'E:\hudba\test.ps1' does not exist. At line:1 char:1 + Move-Item "E:\test\*" "E:\ ... + CategoryInfo     : InvalidOperation: (:) [Move-Item], PSInvalidOperationException   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand
```

The scripts

```
Move-Item "E:\test\*" "E:\test2" -Exclude "*.ps1"

Get-ChildItem -Path "E:\test\*" -Recurse -Exclude "*.ps1" | Move-Item -Destination "E:\test2"
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue, and is slated for v6 to fix

https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2385